# Ebizmart MailChimp Magento2

Tags: magento2

I am using `Ebizmart_Mailchimp` in `Magento 2`, I upgrade my `MailChimp` extension but now order not sync I am getting log:

```
"SubscriberNew": 100,
    "ProductNew": 100,
    "CustomerNew": 100,
    "QuoteNew": 68
```

why order not coming ? How I debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, not all orders are synced, if your order contains only not supported products, then the order will be not synced.
In the last versions, you can see the status of the order (as an icon) in the order grid, what do you see there?